# Python: Why else statement can be discarded in this simple expression?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I apologize for how obvious this answer must be, but I just can't seem to find out why an else statement isn't needed in the following function which returns True -

```
def boolean():
    x = 1
    if x == 1:
        return True
    return False

boolean()
```

My beginner coding mind is confused why False isn't being returned. The if statement returns True, then outside of that if statement, False is returned. I would've thought to write -

```
def boolean():
    x = 1
    if x == 1:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

boolean()
```

Why isn't the else statement needed here? Thank you very much for enlightening me on this.

Comment: "The if statement returns True, then outside of that if statement, False is returned", how can two values be returned from a function? And why not just `return x == 1`?

Comment: For some reason, I wasn't sure that only one value can be returned from a function. And `return x == 1` would be a better way of writing that, instead of an if statement which isn't needed. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The execution of a function always ends as soon as a *return* statement is run. Nothing past that point is even evaluated. For example, if you added a print statement immediately after the *return* statement, you would not see it printed in the console.

Similarly, the execution of this function never reaches `return False` because True was already returned.

Comment: Awe, now that makes a lot more sense. Thank you!